# How to set Application State value within a class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, global-variables, application-state

In the App_Code folder, I created a new class in which I wanted to set the value of an Application State variable.

In order to read from Application State, I used the following code:

```
string text = (string)HttpContext.Current.Application["text"];
```

But now I want to set the value of the Application State. I had tried the following code, but it didn't work:

```
System.Web.HttpApplicationState.Application["text"] = "string";
```

What's the right way to set the value of an Application State variable?

Comment: how did you know it didn't work ?

Comment: Visual Studio underlined "Application" in red, and said: "'System.Web.HttpApplicationState' does not contain a definition for 'Application'"

Comment: if I got your question correctly, why don't you use the same method of reading when you want to write? `HttpContext.Current.Session["text"] = YOUR_VALUE;`

Comment: From what I've read this method is for reading only. Are you sure it'll work? Visual Studio seems to accept it.

Comment: @MohammedElSayed mentioned the correct thing , you should be using either of the two for read and write.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Application["text"] = "string";
```

When you are setting the value in code behind file of a page, you can simply use:

```
Application["text"]="string";
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please use in the following manner ?

To write the Application State as :

```
System.Web.HttpApplicationState.Application["text"] = "string";
```

And read them as

```
string text = (string)Application["text"];
```

Try this .

Answer (score 1):

the technique to read/write application/session variables from outside your page code (say a class file) is the same, you must explicitly point to the current HTTP Context before moving forward.

as an example so to read any application variable, use the following line:

`var myVariable = HttpContext.Current.Application["PROPERTY_NAME"]`

and to write back a value, use the following line

`HttpContext.Current.Application["PROPERTY_NAME"] = YOUR_VALUE`

the same thing applies to `Session` variables.

P.S: I'm the one who suggested this first, see my comment above. :)